# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ValidationError' Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create Views.py method where I check if the email already exists in the database. It worked for username but it is not working for emails or tokens. What would be the way to make that possible? Thank you!

```js
@api_view(['POST'])
def send_user_details(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        serializer = SignUpDetailsForm(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():

            email = serializer.validated_data['email']
            username = serializer.validated_data['username']
            password = serializer.validated_data['password']

            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                raise email.ValidationError("Este Email ya está en uso")

            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                raise username.ValidationError("Este Usuario ya está en uso")
```

This is the serializer:

```js
class SignUpDetailsForm(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SignUpDetails
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'username',
            'password',
        )
```

It generates AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ValidationError'

Comment: Python clearly says that `email` object which is 'str' object has no attribute 'ValidationError' .

Comment: @madzohan ok, the username is a string as well, though it doesn't get this error.

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#tutorial-1-serialization

Comment: It cannot be True :) run python with a= 'ololo'; a.ValidationError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use `raise email.ValidationError(…)`. `email` is a `str`ing, and a string has no `ValidationError` attribute. It is also non-sensical, since the variable email does not contain the word email.

Your username is not validated either: that is done by the serializer, and the serializer simply errors on this because the `username` field of the `User` model requires the `username` to be unique. Therefore the serializer will validate this.

## Option 1: validating by the serializer

You can implement logic for the email as well. For example by defining your own model, or by adding a [**`UniqueValidator`** [DRF-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquevalidator) to the email serialization field:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator

class SignUpDetailsForm(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SignUpDetails
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'username',
            'password',
        )
        extra_kwargs = {
            'email': {
                'validators': [UniqueValidator(queryset=SignUpDetails.objects.all())]
            }
        }
```

Now the serializer will thus check if the email is unique, and raise an error otherwise. You thus should *not* do validation in the view, this belongs in the serialization layer.

## Option 2: Specifying uniqness for an email field

If you defined your own user model, you can make the email field unique as well, then the user model looks like:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class SignUpDetails(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        _('email address')
        unique=True
    )
    # …
```

Comment: Ok, the simplest way would be to create my own User Registration model and set email as Unique, right?

Comment: @IvanStepanchuk: isn't `SignUpDetails` you user model? If you do not have one, you can simply add a `UniqueValidator` as in option 1. There are thus two ways to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider migrating these checks to the `SignUpDetailForm`:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class SignUpDetailForm(forms.Form):
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise ValidationError('Este Email ya está en uso')
    
    def clean_username(self):
        ...
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Comment: I have tried and my serializer doesn't even see that. It just posts without triggering any error.

Answer (score 0):

---

Are you sure it works for `username`?
AFAIK, we should raise ValidationError just as an object of exception.

We should not expect that any of the value from form will raise this exception.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
    raise ValidationError("Este Email ya está en uso")
```

Comment: It did work with the user, the form gets the message that this username already exists. But when it comes to email this is where this str error appears. The idea that you gave returns this error:
line 33, in send_user_details
    raise ValidationError("Este Email ya está en uso")
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['Este Email ya está en uso']

Comment: When I use that with username, it says "username: A user with that username already exists." and it doesn't show the string message that I put into ValidationError. And when used with email it returns the error above.

Comment: @IvanStepanchuk: that error is generated by the *serializer*, not by your error handling.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ok, in that case what might be the problem? According to the serializer username and email receive the same treatment, though it works with username but not with email?

Comment: @IvanStepanchuk: because a standard user model has a `unique=True` constraint on the `username` but *not* on the `email` field. Therefore the serializer that is constructed will validate the uniqness of a username, but not of an email. You can however make the `email` field unique for your model